# How to batch truncate a file by a set amount of bytes?

Tags: windows-7, batch, hex-editor

I have ~300 files that need to be truncated (I need to remove a specified number of bytes from the beginning of the file). I can do it one by one using a hex file editor, but given the number of files I have to process that would be a rather overwhelming task.

Is there an automated solution for this? (Operating system is Windows 7 64bit.)

Comment: Your best bet is to use PowerShell. It should be pre-installed with the O.S. I'm not on a Windows machine now, but I'll come back with an answer tomorrow, if noone comes up with one. Here's a clue though: http://www.sans.org/windows-security/2010/02/11/powershell-byte-array-hex-convert

Answer (score 5):

`dd` has a skip option.

Per file You can use `dd if=MyFile of=my_new_file skip=BytesToSkip`

Optionally in a loop (e.g. in bash in the target directory)
`for a in * ; do echo processing $a ; dd if=$a of=$a.shorter skip=300 ;  done`

Adjust skip with the correct number of bytes, KB or MB
If the files are large playing with the block size (bs=X) might speed things up.

Comment: Tell that to Windows... :)

Comment: There was no win7 tag yet when I started my answer. Anyway, how big are the files? Small enough for a quick move to a unix host? Large enough to warrant installing extra tools?

Comment: `dd` is [available for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) too. In `CMD` the loop could be done like this: `for %a in (*.*) do dd if=%a of=%a.shorter skip=300`.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go...

Powershell code:

```
$PATH = "d:\My Dir"
$BYTES_TO_TRIM = 10

$files = dir $PATH | where { !$_.PsIsContainer }

foreach ($file in $files) {
    Write-Output "File being truncated: $($file.FullName)"
    Write-Output "  Original Size: $($file.Length) bytes"
    Write-Output "  Truncating $BYTES_TO_TRIM bytes..."
    $byteEncodedContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.FullName)
    $truncatedByteEncodedContent = $byteEncodedContent[$BYTES_TO_TRIM..($byteEncodedContent.Length - 1)]
    Set-Content -value $truncatedByteEncodedContent -encoding byte -path "$($file.FullName)"

    Write-Output "  Size after truncation: $((Get-Item $file.FullName).Length) bytes"
    Write-Output "Truncation done!`n"
}
```

Comment: This script gives the following error: "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.."

Comment: @dtmland I didn't thought of 100 GB files when I wrote it. If you want you can come with a byte-by-byte reading solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without loading the whole file into memory:
eg. remove 3 leading bytes from all log files and save copy to `1_<same name>`:

```
set files=*.log
set bytes=3
for %i in (%files%) do set /a size=%~zi-%bytes% >nul & powershell gc "%i" -Encoding byte -Tail !size! ^| sc 1_"%i" -Encoding byte
```

Tested in Win 10 cmd